# Data validation in software

Tags: validation, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

Should the data validation be in the application/business layer or should it part of the data access layer-acting as a gateway to what goes into the data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

- Always validate and/or sanitize user-input.
- Validation in the data access layers facilitates multiple applications without redundant validation code.
- In client/server communications, client-side pre-validation can save a round-trip (when the data is invalid).